# Why does this not work, htaccess, capture domain ext and use in cond

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Why does this rewrite rule not work?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.(se|dk)/shop/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```

I am attempting to catch all requests to domain.dk/shop/ and domain.se/shop/ and redirect them to domain.dk, or domain.se.

What seems to be the issue?

Entire htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Redirect everything to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.(se|dk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop$ https://domain.%1/ [R=302,L,NE]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HTTP_HOST` doesn't have any path information, it is **only** "domain.se". The path information must be in the rule's regex match:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain.(se|dk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^shop$ https://domain.%1/ [R=302,L,NE]
```

Also, you need to use the `%1` backreference, which references a grouping in the condition. The `$1` backreference is one from the rule's grouping (which doesn't have one).

Comment: ah, but i assumed it was a condition, anyway it does not work when i visit domain.se/shop/ i do not get redirected to domain.se, i can post the entire htaccess

Comment: Also the url must have a backslash at the end, i tried with RewriteRule ^shop/$ https://domain.%1/ [R=302,L,NE]

also does not work

Comment: @IvanRistic you need all that redirect stuff (your last 2 rules) **before** your wordpress routing rules. Otherwise, all the routing happens first and you'll never match `/shop/`.